# Overriding hashCode() and equals() methods

Tags: java, overriding, equals, hashcode

1. I override both the hashCode() and equals(), but **I don't modify anything inside the overridden methods**.

   ```
   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
       int hash = 7;
       hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.model);
       hash = 67 * hash + this.year;
       return hash;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       if (obj == null) {
           return false;
       }
       if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
           return false;
       }
       final PC other = (PC) obj;
       if (!Objects.equals(this.model, other.model)) {
           return false;
       }
       if (this.year != other.year) {
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   }
   ```
2. I create 2 identical objects:

   ```
   PC One = new PC();

   One.setModel("HP");

   One.setYear(2013);

   PC Two = new PC();

   Two.setModel("HP");

   Two.setYear(2013);
   ```
3. I compare those 2 objects:

   ```
    if (One.equals(Two)) {

           System.out.println("They are the same objects!");

     } else {

          System.out.println("They are different objects!");
      }
   ```

The result is: "They are the same objects!". However, if I don't override both methods, the result will be: "They are different objects!".
 Because the hashCode is unique for each object (I suppose), I have expected thet the result to be: "They are different objects!".
**Q:** Why?

Comment: What is the superclass of `PC`?

Comment: What does your overriden `equals` look like?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, Class Object, meaning PC has no defined superclass by me.

Comment: @Eran, I have added the overriden equals() and hashCode() in my question.

Comment: Where are you calling hashCode()?  What has the hashCode got to do with the output?  Where do you ensure that objects have different hash codes? (This doesn't happen magically)

Comment: While the answer from John B is bang on, I suggest you to have a look at this for further understanding - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2014/10/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-for-pojo.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `equals` implementation of `Object` uses the instance's reference address. Two `Objects` are equal ONLY if they reside at the same location in memory.

If you don't override `equals` that is the implementation you get.

Also, this behavior has nothing to do with `hashCode` is you are not calling `hashCode`. If you call `equals` directly there is not use of `hashCode`. `hashCode` is generally used in data structures just as `HashMap`.

Answer (score 3):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final PC other = (PC) obj;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.model, other.model)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.year != other.year) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This method you claim to be the default implementation of the equals method is not true. Equals defaults to comparison via the `==` equality operator which compares the 32 or 64 bit pointer references to JVM memory locations. Check this [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Object.java#Object.equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       return (this == obj);
}
```

Comment: I didn't claim that it was the default implementation of the equals() method, though I wanted to make sure about the fact that the equals() method provided in my question is not the default one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't override `equals`, your `PC` objects inherits the [`equals` method from `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), which performs the same thing as `==` -- comparing object references to see if they are the same object.

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

So, your `equals` method returns `true` after comparing the internal contents of your `PC` objects, but when not overridden, `Object`'s `equals` method returns `false` because they are different objects.