# How does the String's indexOf(String obj) method is working without String object?

Tags: java, generics

I'm learning, How to make a dynamic Array. I know there are built-in classes in the Collection API but I just wanted to understand how it actually works under the hood. I took the whole code from here  https://github.com/williamfiset/data-structures/blob/master/com/williamfiset/datastructures/dynamicarray/DynamicArray.java.

This is a generic class and one of the methods in the class  doesn't make sense to me

```java
public boolean remove(Object obj) {
    int index = indexOf(obj);
    if (index == -1) return false;
    removeAt(index);
    return true;
  }
```

The above method checks if the given object is present in the array then it'll call the removeAt() method which will create a new array without that object or return false if the object is not present at all.

1- How does this indexOf() method is working fine here w/o using the String object and w/o iterating over the array.

2- Does this something related to Generic? If yes, please provide some link so I can educate myself on this.

Answer (score 0):

It's using the DynamicArray's indexOf() function, which *does* iterate over the array. You don't have to use a String for this to work. What it does is look if the object in the array .equals() the object passed into the indexOf() function. If it does, then it returns the index.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've lined does indeed use [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). The class is defines as `DynamicArray<T>`, where `<T>` part is the type of Object.

So `DynamicArray<String>` stores `String`s while `DynamicArray<Integer>` stores `Integer`s.

Regardless, `indexOf()` itself doesn't use generics, it simply iterates over the array, looking for the right object using `equals`:

```
  public int indexOf(Object obj) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (obj == null) {
        if (arr[i] == null) return i;
      } else {
        if (obj.equals(arr[i])) return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
```

If the `DynamicArray` contains `String`s, that `equals` call will go to `String.equals`.

Comment: Oh okay got you, How can I be so stupid. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

The indexOf looks for equal object in array and return the index in the array as you can see https://github.com/williamfiset/data-structures/blob/068c10624abab4568433f047fd7be3f24fb40d2a/com/williamfiset/datastructures/dynamicarray/DynamicArray.java#L80

```
public int indexOf(Object obj) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (obj == null) {
        if (arr[i] == null) return i;
      } else {
        if (obj.equals(arr[i])) return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
```

IndeOf returns -1 if doesn't find the searched object in the array.

See [Overriding hashCode() and equals() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242832/overriding-hashcode-and-equals-methods) to learn how to compare generic Object if you don't want use native types