# How to test presenter method that create a new object inside it?

Tags: android, junit, mockito, android-testing

I have this method to validate Unit. I send field values and inside it method I create a new model and then return that model via interface.

```
public void validate(String unitNumber, Integer unitTypeId, String notes) {
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(unitNumber)) {
      Unit unit = new Unit();
      unit.setUnitNumber(unitNumber);
      unit.setFlatTypeId(unitTypeId);
      unit.setNotes(notes);
      view.displayUnitValid(unit);
    } else {
      view.displayUnitNotValid();
    }
  }
```

Now I want do do unit testing of this method with the following code.

```
@Test public void shouldValidateSinceUnitNumberIsValid() {
    // Given
    String unitNumber = "1";

    // When
    presenter.validate(unitNumber, null, null);

    // Then
    Mockito.verify(view).displayUnitValid(new Unit());
 }
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
view.displayUnitValid(
    com.rwar.domain.customers.Unit@57cf54e1
);
-> at com.rwar.presentation.work_orders.AddUnitPresenterTest.shouldValidateSinceUnitNumberIsValid(AddUnitPresenterTest.java:73)
```

Obvisouly there is a problem since I am creating a new Unit instance here:

```
Mockito.verify(view).displayUnitValid(new Unit());
```

And inside **validate()** method I create another instance of Unit.

How I can fix this?

Comment: Seems like your `Unit` objects are not equal. Try to set a unit number for your unit object in your test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working solution that might be useful to someone else:

```
 @Test public void shouldValidateSinceUnitNumberIsValid() {
    // Given
    String unitNumber = "1";

    // When
    presenter.validate(unitNumber, null, null);

    // Then use ArgumentCaptor to get unit value from newly created object inside validate() method
    ArgumentCaptor<Unit> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Unit.class);
    Mockito.verify(view).displayUnitValid(argument.capture());
    // Compare captured argument of Unit number with local unitNumber
    assertEquals(argument.getValue().getUnitNumber(), unitNumber);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the same arguments to your verifying method, e.g.

```java
Unit expected = new Unit()
unit.setUnitNumber(unitNumber);
unit.setFlatTypeId(unitTypeId);
unit.setNotes(notes);
Mockito.verify(view).displayUnitValid(expected);
```

You'll likely have to override your `Unit` classes [equals/hashcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242832/overriding-hashcode-and-equals-methods) method such that they compare their contents and not the instance itself.

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but then I need to change parameters of **validate** method to accept Unit model.

Comment: Is there a way to make it work with my current approach?

Comment: @Zookey: Why do you think you neet to change parameters? It should work like that (if `equals` and `hashcode` are properly implemented). You also have the option to define a custom `ArgumentMatcher`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to do this in Kotlin, you can use Mockito `check` function to make asserts over the `Unit` instance that is passed as an argument of `displayUnitValid()`. Something like this:

```java
Mockito.verify(view).displayUnitValid(Mockito.check { unit ->
    assertEquals(unitNumber, unit.getUnitNumber)
});
```

More info about `check` [here](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/wiki/Mocking-and-verifying#argument-matchers)

Comment: Nice ide, but I am using PowerMockito and I do not see this function. (

Comment: @JaviHerAr: The OP seems to use `Java` not `Kotlin`. The `check` functionality seems to only exist in the `mockito-kotlin` dependency.

Comment: @second you are right, I have updated my answer to clarify it